# Set default option from DB in select box

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a page where user can edit their profile settings. Data are read from db and displayed as default values for many fields like email, city, salutation, first name, last name etc...
But for country field I am getting the list from DB and always the first option is showed (in this case Afghanistan). How can I set this field to default value if user "preselected" the country before? For example if user selected and saved Germany before, I want this option to be shown as default, not Afghanistan.

```
{!!Form::open(array('url' => 'editUserProfile/'.$user->id, 'files' => true))!!}
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstName" value="{{$user->firstName}}" required>
        <select class="form-control" name="country">
            @foreach($countries as $country)
                <option>{{$country->country_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

How can I set `$user->country`as default like for a first name?

Comment: if `$user->country` == `$country->country_name` echo `selected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="country">
    @foreach($countries as $country)
        <option value="{{$country->country_name}}" {{ $country->country_name == $user->country? ' selected' : '' }}>{{$country->country_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I added `value` attribute so as country name can be passed to server.
And added ternary operator for checking if current `$country->country_name` equals to `$user->country`.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
@foreach($countries as $country)
  <option value="{{ $country->id }}" <?php if($user->country_id == $country->id){ echo "selected"; } ?> >{{$country->country_name}}</option>
@endforeach
```